How to retrieve Common Table Expressions (CTEs) as a R list?
Context
I am connected to a PostgreSQL database and I use dplyr + dbplyr to query it. One of the query is quite long and complex and uses multiple CTEs.
Problem
I need to use these CTEs to make some plots and analysis within R but I do not know how to get them as "separated" dataframes within R.
I tried to break down the long query into smaller ones but this obviously fails when one CTE needs a previous one.
Question
How to retrieve the CTEs of a query as a list of dataframes in R?
Example
Please find below a small example illustrating the question. The query is very dumb but I feel it is enough for illustration purpose.
# Packages ----
if(!require("dbplyr")){install.packages("dbplyr")}; library(dbplyr)
if(!require("tidyverse")){install.packages("tidyverse")}; library(tidyverse)

# Set up the example database using the iris dataset ----
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, iris)
# Query using the "WITH" command ----
query = sql(
  "WITH
  tbl_set AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa'),
  tbl_ver AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'versicolor'),
  tbl_all AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_set 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_ver)
SELECT * FROM tbl_all"
)

Expected output
The expected output is an object in the R environment, for example a list containing each CTE as dataframes, see below the expected structure:
# Target output ----
list(
  tbl_set = filter(iris, Species == "setosa"),
  tbl_ver = filter(iris, Species == "versicolor"),
  tbl_all = collect(tbl(con, query))
)
#> $tbl_set
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 
#> $tbl_ver
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 2           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 3           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 4           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 
#> $tbl_all
#> # A tibble: 100 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#> # ℹ 90 more rows

Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0

please clarify ; is the issue that you know how to do it manually, but wanted to automate it in someway? or are you stuck on extracting the sub table even manually  ?

@NirGraham, thaks for your comment, I try to explain it better. I am stuck on extracting the CTEs (here tbl_set , tbl_ver) from the query in a R-list. The idea is to "catch" the CTEs while the query is being executed and store them in an R environment. The list-output in the example is just here to mimic the structure of the expected output. I am looking for a way to get this object from the query execution if that makes sense.

so you are trying to automate it ... I think you would need to write something to parse the query text and identify the sub queries. maybe with regex. but if you only need this for one complex query; its probably going to be easier for your just to copy and paste the subqueries out and solve your issue manually.

@NirGraham, yes, I tried to run each CTE as an independant query. It works when there are no dependency between the CTEs. However, when a CTE_3 relies on a previous CTE_2 it fails. I understand from your comment that it is not possible to grab on the fly the CTEs and store them in a R environment.

I can see a way to do this via regex, though the patterns will cause headaches. Before attempting those - how is the original query generated? You have the dbplyr tag, but no dbplyr translation in the question.

There might be an easier way to answer this from where the query is generated.

@Simon.S.A. I call the original query from R with something like dplyr::collect(dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::sql(readr::read_file(here::here("the_query.sql"))))). It is not (yet) a view in the database. Does this answer your comment?

1) Instead of using CTEs create temporary tables.  Below we have changed the example slightly so that the creation of tbl_ver depends on tbl_set.
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

res <- dbExecute(con, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_set AS
  SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa' ")
res <- dbExecute(con, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_ver AS
  SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'versicolor' AND
    \"Sepal.Length\" > (SELECT avg(\"Sepal.Length\") FROM tbl_set)")

L <- list(
  tbl_set = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_set"),
  tbl_ver = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_ver"),
  tbl_all = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_set
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_ver")
)

dbDisconnect(con)

str(L)

giving
List of 3
 $ tbl_set:'data.frame':        50 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..$ Species     : chr [1:50] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
 $ tbl_ver:'data.frame':        47 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:47] 7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 6.6 5.2 5.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:47] 3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 2.8 3.3 2.9 2.7 3 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:47] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 4.5 4.7 4.6 3.9 4.2 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:47] 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.6 1.3 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Species     : chr [1:47] "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" ...
 $ tbl_all:'data.frame':        97 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:97] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:97] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:97] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:97] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..$ Species     : chr [1:97] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...

2) If the problem is to extract the CTE's then this inputs an SQL
statement with CTE's, extracts them, generates and runs create temoprary table statements and then reads them and the original SQL statement.  (To extract the CTE's we count left and right parentheses and add a @ after the outer ones so that we can later extract the content of the outer parentheses coming after a name and AS.)
library(gsubfn)
library(RSQLite)

sql <- "WITH
  tbl_set AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa'),
  tbl_ver AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'versicolor' AND 
  \"Sepal.Length\" > (SELECT avg(\"Sepal.Length\") FROM tbl_set))
SELECT * FROM tbl_set
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_ver
"

# insert @ after outer parentheses
p <- proto(
  pre = function(this) this$depth <- -1,
  fun = function(this, x) {
    if (x == "(") this$depth <- this$depth + 1
    ret <- if (this$depth == 0) paste0(x, "@") else x
    if (x == ")") this$depth <- this$depth - 1
    ret
  }
)

# extract CTEs
cte <- sql |>
  chartr("\n", " ", x = _) |>
  gsubfn("[\\(\\)]", p, x = _) |>
  strapply("(([a-z_]+) +AS \\(@.*?\\)@)", perl = TRUE) |>
  unlist() |>
  trimws() |> 
  gsub("@", "", x = _)

# cte names
nms <- sub(" .*", "", cte)

# form SQL statements
sqls <- cte |>
  sub("\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", x = _) |>
  paste("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE", ... = _) |>
  gsub(".@", "", x = _) |>
  setNames(nms)

# run statements to create temporary tables from cte's
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
for(s in sqls) dbExecute(con, s)

# get data
L <- c(lapply(nms, dbReadTable, conn = con), 
  list(tbl_all = dbGetQuery(con, sql)))

dbDisconnect(con)


+1 for the edit of the example to make it more relevant than mine :-) and accepted answer for the clarity of the explanation. The key that unlocked the problem was the use of temporary tables instead of CTEs.

I dont really know what your issue is; I guess I'll show you how to split out the CTE's to their own tables? your final query can be altered to use them or not, but the point is that you get them out in your final list.
The approach is boiling down to copy and paste the CTE's code  and add some boilerplate, CREATE TABLE name as  to make the queries concrete.
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
# Set up the example database using the iris dataset ----
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, iris)

original_query <-  sql("WITH
  tbl_set AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa'),
  tbl_ver AS (SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'versicolor'),
  tbl_all AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_set 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_ver)
SELECT * FROM tbl_all")

###   different from above as can use the concrete CTE tables we will make in q1 and q2 
modified_query <-  sql("WITH
  tbl_all AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_set 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_ver)
SELECT * FROM tbl_all")

# make the CTE queries explicit ? 
q1 <- sql("CREATE TABLE tbl_set as SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa'")
q2 <- sql("CREATE TABLE tbl_ver as SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'versicolor'")

dbExecute(conn = con, q1)
dbExecute(conn = con, q2)

list(
  tbl_set = tbl(con, "tbl_set") |> collect(),
  tbl_ver = tbl(con, "tbl_ver") |> collect(),
  tbl_all = tbl(con, original_query) |> collect(),
  tbl_all2 = tbl(con, modified_query) |> collect() # works just as well 
)


The issue is that, this technique fails when one CTE needs a previous one. Here, if tbl_set needs tbl_ver then it is not possible to run q2. I tried to keep the example as simple as possible thus the CTEs in it are not dependent but the real-world query does have dependencies between CTEs.

if tbl_set needs tbl_ver, then CREATE TABLE tbl_ver first; and then you can rewrite the tbl_set query to use that.. I guess I'll edit my answer to show how you would change your original query to use the concrete tbl_set and tbl_ver that were made, since it depends on them...

You can use dbplyr to create references to remote data frames that will behave for most purposes exactly like CTEs. I illustrate that in a note I wrote here.
The following produces the list you're looking for. But I wonder if you really need to be collect-ing your data frames.
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# Set up the example database using the iris dataset ----
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
iris <- copy_to(con, iris)

tbl_set <- iris |> filter(Species == 'setosa')
tbl_ver <- iris |> filter(Species == 'versicolor')

tbl_all <-
  tbl_set |>
  union_all(tbl_ver)

tbl_all
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 5]
#> # Database: DuckDB v1.0.0 [root@Darwin 23.6.0:R 4.4.1/:memory:]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ℹ more rows


dbs <- list(tbl_set, tbl_ver, tbl_all)

map(dbs, collect)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 50 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 50 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>  1          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>  4          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  5          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>  6          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#>  7          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
#>  8          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor
#>  9          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 10          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 100 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ℹ 90 more rows

Created on 2024-07-06 with reprex v2.1.0
